# parsererror: SyntaxError: Unexpected token less than sign

Tags: javascript, ajax, coldfusion

I have the following ColdFusion function:

```
component {
url._cf_nodebug=true;
url.returnformat = "json";
url.queryformat = "column";

remote function Read(StateID) {
    local.result = {};
    local.result.MSG = "";
    // local.result.QRY = QueryNew();
    local.svc = new query();
    local.svc.addParam(value=arguments.StateID,cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer");
    local.svc.setSQL("SELECT *
        FROM State WHERE StateID = ?");
    local.svc.setName = "qry";
    local.obj = local.svc.execute();
    local.result.QRY = local.obj.getResult();
    return local.result;
}
}
```

And when I test it from test.cfm, it works correctly:

```
<cfset qry = CreateObject("component","ajaxEnabled").Read(154)>
```

So I think the problem is how I'm passing my parameters into the $.ajax method.
When I call it, I get: parsererror: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

```
;(function($, window, undefined) {
    var document = window.document;
    $('#States').on('click','a',function() {
        var local = {};
        local.data = {};
        local.data.StateID = $(this).data('stateid');
        local.dataType = 'json';
        local.context = $(this)[0];
        local.Promise = $.ajax('ajaxEnabled.cfc',local);
        local.Promise.fail(function(A,B,C) {
            console.log(B + ': ' + C);
        });
    });
})(jQuery, window);
```

I can see in the console that local.data.StateID = 153, which is what I want.

Here's [the link to the page](http://www.phillipsenn.com/Matrix/CRUD/jqm/ajaxEnabled/ajaxEnabled.cfm).  And [here's the link to test.cfm](http://www.phillipsenn.com/Matrix/CRUD/jqm/ajaxEnabled/test.cfm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're specifying the CFC in your AJAX call, but not which method to call. So CF is interpretting the request as one to see the API docs for that CFC, and that's what it's returning to the browser. So the AJAX call is receiving mark-up, not JSON.

Also, in future: when you say you get an error and you're dealing with multiple systems (eg: CF and JS), make sure to say which system is giving you the error. This saves us having to guess.

Comment: Thanks Adam!  Yeah, I said aloud "Oh!  It's because I'm not specifying a method!" I rushed back here to Mea culpa to see that you had answered it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem has nothing to do with your JavaScript code itself... it has to do with what you are doing server side.  If you use your browser tools, you will see this response:

```
<br> <br>
Unsupported Operation. Check application log for more details.
<br> <br>
```

The parser error is for the returned data, not your code.

The URL in this case was http://www.phillipsenn.com/CFIDE/componentutils/cfcexplorer.cfc?method=getcfcinhtml&name=Matrix.CRUD.jqm.ajaxEnabled.ajaxEnabled&path=/Matrix/CRUD/jqm/ajaxEnabled/ajaxEnabled.cfc

Comment: Oh!  That gives me an idea!

Comment: I get that when I try to navigate to the [http://www.phillipsenn.com/Matrix/CRUD/jqm/ajaxEnabled/ajaxEnabled.cfc?StateID=154](cfc directly).